# How do I correctly digitally sign a SAML2.0 AuthnRequest?

Tags: digital-signature, saml-2.0

I have a working SAML2.0 Single Sign On system built in coffeescript on express / nodejs.

I use [SSOCircle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/) to test my SSO and can successfully authenticate there with either HTTP-POST or HTTP-REDIRECT binding. So far so good.

Now I need to digitally sign my authentication request.

To do this I have used the nodejs [xml-crytpo](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto) library. This results in SAML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest Version="2.0" ID="_1C8A2EFA-2644-4330-9A36-2B45547ECFAF" IssueInstant="2014-10-14T16:06:27.769Z" Destination="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/ssocircle" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <saml:Issuer>http://app.localhost</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" />
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="#_1C8A2EFA-2644-4330-9A36-2B45547ECFAF">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>m4qHiXM82TuxY31l6+QSECHEHc0=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>fps0I0Rp02qDK0BPTK7Lh+ ...</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>MIICuDCCAaCgAwIBAgIQEVFtJk ...</X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

The certificate information contained in the digital signature has been removed for brevity but it comes from a `pem` file I generated locally (self-signed).

I also updated my Service Provider metadata supplied to SSOCircle to include the SAML attributes `AuthnRequestsSigned` and `WantAssertionsSigned`, like this:

```
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="http://app.localhost" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        ...
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Sending my `AuthnRequest` without the digital signature works fine. When I include the digital signature it fails with a statuscode of `500` and a generic 'Invalid Request' message.

How do I correctly digitally sign my `AuthnRequest` so it works against SSOCircle?

Thanks.

#### Edit 1 - Add Cert Key to the SP Metadata

Following suggestions in the comments I have now added the appropriate `KeyDescriptor` attributes to my sp-metadata to include my self-signed certificate's public-key.

```
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="http://app.localhost" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509SubjectName>CN=app.localhost</ds:X509SubjectName>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIICu ... wg==</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIICu ... wg==</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        ...
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

I have included two `KeyDescriptor` elements, one specifying the `use` = `signing` and the other specifying the `use` = `encryption`, although I think the latter is redundant (as I am running over TLS) and will be ignored by the IdP.

This does not work and I get the same error:

> Reason: The SAML Request is invalid.

#### Edit 2 - Self Signed Cerificates

**Theory**: I cannot use a self-signed certificate. Instead I must use a certificate that is known to and trusted by SSOCircle

**Result**: This was disproved. You can use a self-signed cert just as long as the correct public key is included in the sp-metadata.

#### Edit 3 - Added Correct `Transform` Algorithm

I have now updated my signature to specify the  `#enveloped-signature` transformation algorithm.

```
        <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
```

Also I found that the correct structure for the included x509 certificate public key was the following (note the inner `X509Certificate` element):

```
<KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>MIID...MMxZ</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

I am now using the [TestShib](https://www.testshib.org/index.html) site to run against as this allows access to the IdP logs which provides more detailed and useful information.

#### Edit 4 - Swapping the SAML Element Order to Match Schema

According to answer given by @Hos (see below) the order of the SAML elements must match the Schema. Therefore the `signature` element must appear directly after the `issuer` element, like this:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest Version="2.0" ID="_782F6F1E-1B80-4D7D-B26C-AC85030D9300" IssueInstant="2014-10-28T11:45:49.412Z" Destination="https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/ssocircle" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <saml:Issuer>http://app.localhost9de83841</saml:Issuer>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="#_782F6F1E-1B80-4D7D-B26C-AC85030D9300">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>pjXEtbAFMJA3hWhD/f6lxJTshTg=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>FY1...Qg==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIID...MMxZ</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

This still fails SSOCircle with an opaque 500 error. However TestShib shows the following log:

```
11:02:37.292 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.common.security.MetadataPKIXValidationInformationResolver:631] - Write lock over cache acquired
11:02:37.292 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.common.security.MetadataPKIXValidationInformationResolver:634] - Added new PKIX info to entity cache with key: [http://app.localhost9de83841,{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor,urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol,SIGNING]
11:02:37.292 - DEBUG [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.common.security.MetadataPKIXValidationInformationResolver:637] - Write lock over cache released
11:02:37.293 - WARN [edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.idp.profile.saml2.SSOProfileHandler:406] - Message did not meet security requirements
org.opensaml.ws.security.SecurityPolicyException: **Validation of protocol message signature failed**
```

As I read this, the public key used to validate the signature has been extracted from the sp-metadata:

```
Added new PKIX info to entity cache with key: [http://app.localhost9de83841,{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}SPSSODescriptor,urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol,SIGNING]
```

However the actual validation has failed, presumably because the digest values do not match. Which means the digest being calculated by xmlcrypto is different from the digest calculated by ShibTest. This can surely only be for one of two reasons:

- The algorithms used by xmlcrypto and TestShib to generate the digest are somehow different
- The public keys do not match.

A minute examination of the keys show they are the same. So here is my code in case you can spot anything.

**Note**: This code relies on the nodejs [xmlbuilder](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js) and [xml-crytpo](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto) libraries)

```
getSamlRequest:(idpUrl, requestId, next)->
    request = @xmlbuilder.create
        'samlp:AuthnRequest':
            '@xmlns:samlp':'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'
            '@xmlns:saml': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion'
            '@Version': '2.0'
            '@ID': requestId
            '@IssueInstant': (new Date()).toISOString()
            '@Destination': idpUrl
            'saml:Issuer': '@@spEntityId'
        ,null
        ,headless: true
    request.comment 'insert-signature'
    request.element 'samlp:NameIDPolicy':
                        '@AllowCreate': 'true'
    saml = request.end()
    #Your self-signed pem file that contains both public and private keys. 
    #The public key must also be included in your sp-metadata
    certFilePath = "certs/sp-certificate.pem"
    @fs.readFile certFilePath, (err, certificate)=>
        signer = new @xmlcrypto.SignedXml()
        signer.signingKey = certificate
        signer.addReference "//*[local-name(.)='AuthnRequest']", ['http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature']
        signer.keyInfoProvider = new =>
            getKeyInfo: (key)=>
                public_key = /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----([^-]*)-----END CERTIFICATE-----/g.exec(key)[1].replace /[\r\n|\n]/g, ''
                "<X509Data><X509Certificate>#{public_key}</X509Certificate></X509Data>"
        signer.computeSignature saml
        signature = signer.getSignatureXml()
        signed = saml.replace '<!-- insert-signature -->', signature
        return next null, signed
```

#### Edit 5 - Trace of Requests

Below is a trace of the requests made during the SAML handshake with SSOCircle. The output was generated by the nodejs [request](https://github.com/request/request) module in conjunction with the [request-debug](https://github.com/request/request-debug) module.

I have included some clarification notes below this trace output.

```
{ request: 
   { debugId: 17,
     uri: 'http://localhost:8082/security/sso/subscription/dev2/096b75a2-4a55-4eec-83c8-d2509e948b07',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: { host: 'localhost:8082' } } }
{ response: 
   { debugId: 17,
     headers: 
      { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'origin, x-requested-with, accept, content-type',
        'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE',
        date: 'Wed, 05 Nov 2014 16:55:49 GMT' },
     statusCode: 200,
     body: '{"RequestId":"_F7DDDD24-32C6-420E-A550-95872D30033B","SubscriptionName":"Develop-2","SubscriptionURL":"dev2","IdentityProviderCertificateFile":"ssocircle.cer","IdentityProviderDestinationUrl":"https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/ssocircle","SAMLBinding":"HttpPost"}' } }
{ request: 
   { debugId: 18,
     uri: 'https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/SSOPOST/metaAlias/ssocircle',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: 
      { host: 'idp.ssocircle.com:443',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'content-length': 3492 },
     body: 'SAMLRequest=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%2BPFRyYW5zZm9ybXM%2BPFRyYW5zZm9ybSBBbGdvcml0aG09Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvMDkveG1sZHNpZyNlbnZlbG9wZWQtc2lnbmF0dXJlIiAvPjwvVHJhbnNmb3Jtcz48RGlnZXN0TWV0aG9kIEFsZ29yaXRobT0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC8wOS94bWxkc2lnI3NoYTEiIC8%2BPERpZ2VzdFZhbHVlPjBLdUtNVG1Zc29Wb1BlTXhtdDhuNml2M3RxZz08L0RpZ2VzdFZhbHVlPjwvUmVmZXJlbmNlPjwvU2lnbmVkSW5mbz48U2lnbmF0dXJlVmFsdWU%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%2BPC9LZXlJbmZvPjwvU2lnbmF0dXJlPjxzYW1scDpOYW1lSURQb2xpY3kgQWxsb3dDcmVhdGU9InRydWUiLz48L3NhbWxwOkF1dGhuUmVxdWVzdD4%3D' } }
{ response: 
   { debugId: 18,
     headers: 
      { server: '"SSOCircle Web Server"',
        date: 'Wed, 05 Nov 2014 16:55:48 GMT',
        'content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
        connection: 'close',
        'set-cookie': [Object],
        'transfer-encoding': 'chunked' },
     statusCode: 500,
     body: '\n\n\n\n<html><head><title>\n            Error Page\n            \n        </title>\n    <link href="/css/bx.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>\n    <body>\n        <div id="myheader">\n            <h1><img src="/logo.png" alt="IDPee - Put your LOGO here" height="65" width="180">&nbsp;</h1>\n        </div>\n        <div id="mycontent">\n            <div id="mynav">\n                <ul>\n                \n                </ul>\n            </div>\n            <div id="mybox">\n                <p>\n                    \n                    <h2>Error occurred</h2>\n<p>\nReason: Invalid signature in Request.\n</p>\n\n                    \n                </p>\n            </div>\n            \n        </div>\n        <div id="myfooter">\n            \n            Copyright &copy; SSOCircle/IDPee.com\n            \n            \n        </div>\n    </body>\n</html>\n\n\n\n' } }
error:  message=Something went wrong whilst trying to automatically log you in. Please try again., name=SSOFailure, message=An error occurred whilst processing the SSO Request., name=SSORequestFailure, message=The IdP failed to successfully process the SAMLRequest and returned an statuscode of 500., name=SamlRequestInvalid, url=http://app.localhost/security/saml2/request
```

**Request `debugId`= 17**: This is the call made by my client into my nodejs proxy server that kicks of the SAML handshake.

**Response`debugId`= 17**: A 200 OK response from the proxy server back to the client. The client now waits to be redirected once the SAML handshake concludes.

**Request `debugId`= 18**: The SAMLRequest is POSTed to the SSOCircle SAML endpoint

**Response`debugId`= 18**: A 500 Internal Server Error response from SSOCircle plus an HTML error page payload.

Comment: Does your IdP trusts your self-signed certificate?

Comment: Are you using POST or Redirect when you get the error message?

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov: No, I have not told SSOCircle about the cert. I didn't think they needed to know because I have included the cert in the body of the signature as x509 data. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Stefan: I have tried both bindings but now I am sticking to using HTTP-POST to prevent the url-length restriction coming into play (and because it just better practice I reckon).

Comment: @biofractal The whole point of signature processing on IdP side is to verify message integrity and message authorship. With self-signed cert message integrity can be verified, but if IdP doesn't trust your cert it can't know that it was YOU (and not some very very bad another person) who sent the request. So yes - it might be the problem.

Comment: If you're using Http Redirect, the signature should be in a separate query string param - not in the XML itself. But for POST it should work.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Please see the Edit above. Can you confirm that it is normal to inform the IdP of the signing certificate other than through the metadata? In other words, do you need to register it with the IdP somehow? I gave read this is not the case but I would appreciate confirmation. Thanks.

Comment: @biofractal Either your certificate must be signed whith one of certification authorities that are trusted by SSOCircle (they even have their own CA http://www.ssocircle.com/en/portfolio/x-509-pki/) or you must add your certificate signer (in this case yourself) to IdP truststore (in case of public available IdP like SSOCircle I don't think they will add your cert)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Please see Edit 2 above. I think you are on to the answer. I have auto-generated and enrolled a new cert with SSOCircle but still receive the same error.

Comment: Don't know what's the particular problem - error messafe is very generic. Have you tried SAML debugging tools from SSOCircle? http://www.ssocircle.com/en/knowledge-center/toolbox/

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I note from the SSOCircle IdP metadata that the `WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false"`. I am not sure if this means they do not support digital signing, or that is is not absolutely required.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I have tried running the same request through TestShib (which allow you to examine the logs) and see the following error: `Signature was missing the required Enveloped signature transform`. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Seems like you missing `<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>` in your signature. More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-EnvelopedSignature

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Please see Edit 3 for progress of sorts. At least I now understand why the #enveloped-signature algorithm was so crucial.

Comment: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManSigErrors and check again that your testshib trusts your certificate itself or it's CA

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I have started a new question to re-focus. Please see: [Generating an enveloped signature for a SAML Request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26506822/776476)

Answer (score 2):

Concerning Edit2: A self signed certificate is sufficient for SSOCircle as long as it was included into the service provider's metadata.

Concerning Edit3: Please move the signature element right after the issuer element. The request must comply to the schema:

```
<sequence>
<element ref="saml:Issuer" minOccurs="0"/>
<element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="0"/>
<element ref="samlp:Extensions" minOccurs="0"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: I have implemented the changes you suggest. Thanks. Please see Edit 4.

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a complete trace of requests. Can you provide a log or s.th. which includes all http requests sent?

Comment: Please see Edit 5 for a complete SP request / response trace. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. At SSOCircle the signature digest value comparison failed. Guess this is what you expected.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the problem. It must be a certificate issue. I have used a self-signed cert and, as an experiment, the certificate SSOCircle assigned to my browser (possibly a CA certificate?) but both give the same digest-value-comparison-failure problem. Maybe its a problem with the xmlcrypto component. I will chase the author up.

Comment: Could it be anything to do with the way I am converting my pfx cert file to a pem file? I am using openssl to do this with the nodes option to prevent the private-key being encrypted: `openssl pkcs12 -in "my-cert.pfx" -out my-cert.pem -nodes`